# SBS2008 Remoteapp certificate not trusted, tried everything

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate, windows-sbs, trusted-root-certificates

I imported the SBS2008 server certificate to the client from where I want to connect.
This worked, and I have added it to the trust root map.

However the error still appears saying that the certficate is not from a valid trusted source.
See the pictures attached.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a number of resons for this. From the top of my head:

- Check the validity of the cert, as in start date and end date.
- Check the date on your PC
- Is the site name on the certificate the same you are using to connect to the machine ? (for instance, the certificate may be published by a machine called SERVER.contoso.com, but you are using another name to connect (dyndns or similar)

Comment: Great comment, thanks ! 

1. Yes it's valid
2. The date on pc is ok
3. You are right, I use the static ip instead of the hostname to connect :-)
This is because the client is not on servers lan. I will add the entry in the hosts file of the client and forward it to the ip I now use to connect.

Comment: You guys are great ! That was the problem. I added the dns to the hostfile with ip and now it works.. They should change their error message because now it is misleading.